# How to sum and divide in MySql

Tags: mysql, syntax

Alright, so I have a user table and would like to get the max value for the user with the highest amount of points divided by a score. Below is a *rough* idea of what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT MAX(SUM(points)/SUM(score)) FROM users
```

I'm not interested in adding up both columns and dividing, rather I'm interested in dividing the points and score for each user and retrieve the highest value out of the lot.

Comment: Does SELECT MAX(points/score) FROM users not work?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could do this with a subquery:

```
Select max(points_over_Score)
from 
    (Select points/score AS points_over_score
    from users);
```

And as thesunneversets mentioned in a comment, that can probably be shortened to

```
SELECT MAX(points/score) FROM users;
```

You're written description of what you're trying to do doesn't make it clear why your example has `SUM` in it, so I didn't use it.

Also, code questions like this one are more appropriate for [stackoverflow.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions). You can flag your own question to ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: Actually, that worked perfectly. I figured it would add both the points and score (as in ALL points and scores) and then go from there, but it appears to do it as I wanted. One last question: how can I get the value in decimal form (if the number comes out to a decimal?)

Comment: The query you posted worked exactly as I wished. I was saying I thought that a query like that would result in both columns being added and returning the result of points being divided by score, rather than returning the highest points/score. Now I just need to have it so if the result is a decimal, it will return as a decimal rather than being rounded.

Answer (score 0):

FrustratedWithFormsDesigner's answer won't work if you need to sum up all of the points, then all of the scores, and then divide the two. That answer divides each point by the score, then returns the highest answer.

This should work:

```
SELECT MAX(sum_points / sum_score) from 
(SELECT SUM(points) as sum_points, SUM(score) as sum_score FROM users)
```

BTW, this returns an "unusual" percentage. You probably want to divide score by points. For example, if you get 70 out of 100, that is 70%, or score (70) / points (100).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is due to the age of this post or version of MySQL at the time, but when I tried the above solutions the following error was thrown:

> ERROR 1248 (42000) : Every derived table must have its own alias

I was able to resolve this using the following:

`SELECT MAX(sum_points / sum_score) from (SELECT SUM(points) as sum_points, SUM(score) as sum_score FROM users) as max_value;`